# Difference between any and length more than/equal to 1

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to evaluate whether there is any elements in an object (series in the following example). I used `any` and I couldn't understand it's behavior. I am wondering why `len(s)>=1` returns True while `any(s)` return False?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.array([0])
s = pd.Series(data)
print(s)
print(len(s))
print(len(s)>=1)
print(any(s))
```

Comment: `any()` returns True if any element of the iterable is True

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  What didn't you understand from the documentation for `len` and `any`?

Comment: `any`'s behavior is confusing

Comment: `any` and `all` are actually very useful. `any` is equivalent to placing `or` between every element in a sequence and `all` is equivalent to placing `and` between every element in a sequence. So `any([x,y,z])` is equivalent to `x or y or z` for logical tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function is a short-circuiting boolean test of all elements of **inside** a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) or [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable):

```
>>> any([0,0,0])
False
>>> any([0,0,1])
True
```

The sequence itself is `True` unless it is empty or has 0 length:

```
>>> bool([]),bool('')
(False, False)
>>> bool([0]),bool('0')
(True, True)
```

The Python function [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) returns the length of a sequence and is completely unrelated to `any`.

Although you could force `len` to be like `any` I suppose:

```
>>> bool(len([e for e in [0,0,0] if bool(e)]))
False
>>> bool(len([e for e in [0,0,1] if bool(e)]))
True
```

(An iterable, such as a generator, may not support `len` but `any` can still be used on these iterables.)

To answer your question of *I am wondering why len(s)>=1 returns True while any(s) return False?* you need to understand [Truth Value Testing in Python](https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/truth.html)

**All objects** are `True` in Python **except**:

1. `None`;
2. `0` in a numeric object;
3. Empty containers, mappings or sequences (those where `len(obj)==0`);
4. A user written object that has defined its own notion of true or false.

So `any(s)` is `False` because all the elements of the sequence `s` are `False` while `len(s)>1` indicates that `s` contains objects and therefor `bool(s)` would be `True`.

This is way simpler, once understood, than other languages sense of 'truthiness', such as [Perl's](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=495975)

---

Pandas [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [len](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.size.html) methods mirror the Python built-in functions.

Comment: Ah it makes sense. Just wondering why a non-boolean value returns True? For example `any(['0'])` returns True.

Comment: Because `'0'` is `True` in Python. Try `bool('0')` And note that `'0'` is not the same as `0`. All strings except `''` are `True` in Python. Almost all objects are True except a limited [few](https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/truth.html)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just one more questions on this: print(bool([0]))
print(any([0])) : how these two are different?

Comment: Look again at the link Truth Value Testing in Python. A sequence in only `False` if it is empty so `[0]` is True as a sequence so `bool([0])` is `True`. `any([0])` is testing the individual elements of the sequence, `bool(0)` is `False` so `any([0])` would be `False`